# For Each element in a ListBox, Start a task and wait for it to finish before moving on

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a **ListBox** populated with a lot of elements. So basically i want to initiate instance of my secondary class which is suppose to the main work and when it's done, move on to the next element in the ListBox and repeat the process till the end while obviously keeping the GUI free. I'm going to post the pseudo-code of my secondary class to give you all an idea about it's working.

```vb
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Demo

    Private Ip As String
    Private Port As Integer
    Private SW As SomeWork  
    Private mre As New ManualResetEvent(False)

    Public Event OnPacket(ByVal Data As SomeMessage)

    Sub New(ByVal Ip As String, ByVal Port As Integer)
        'Self Explantory
    End Sub

    Sub Connect()
        SW = New SomeWork(IP, Port)
        SW.ProcessForMounting(AddressOf InitiateCallback, mre)
        Validate(mre)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Validate(ByVal mre As ManualResetEvent)
        'Some Work here
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitiateCallback(ByVal client As Example)
        client.BufferCallbacks(AddressOf SomeCallBack, mre)                 
    End Sub

    Private Sub SomeCallBack(ByVal Data As SomeMessage)
        'either this or raising the event on main gui
        Dim type As String = Data.Type.ToString()

        Select Case type
            Case is = "Done"
                ' Finished work
                ' Writes something to the server and calls Done() method
                ' On the calling class, move to the next element  
        End Select 
        'Or RaiseEvent Packet(Data)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Done()
        SW.Dispose()
        SW = Nothing
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now, the issue is if i put **Connect()** method in a thread, it's going to exit after the last line in the method without waiting for **SomeCallBack()** to receive **Done**

Once again it is just a pseudo code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way if the processing should be done one by one to introduce a `Boolean` field which indicates if the last callback has finished. The `Connect()` method can be called with `Await` on the caller side so that the UI will not freeze.

```vb
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Demo

    Private Ip As String
    Private Port As Integer
    Private SW As SomeWork  
    Private mre As New ManualResetEvent(False)

    ' Introduce a flag to indicate if the work is done
    Private processingFinished As Boolean = False

    Public Event OnPacket(ByVal Data As SomeMessage)

    Sub New(ByVal Ip As String, ByVal Port As Integer)
        'Self Explantory
    End Sub

    ' Instead of Sub Connect() we use the Async/Await feature
    ' so that this method result can be awaited.
    ' On the caller side use: Await Connect()
    Async Function Connect() As Task
        processingFinished = False
        SW = New SomeWork(IP, Port)
        SW.ProcessForMounting(AddressOf InitiateCallback, mre)
        Validate(mre)

        ' Waiting until work is done.
        While Not processingFinished
            Await Task.Delay(1000);
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub Validate(ByVal mre As ManualResetEvent)
        'Some Work here
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitiateCallback(ByVal client As Example)
        client.BufferCallbacks(AddressOf SomeCallBack, mre)                 
    End Sub

    Private Sub SomeCallBack(ByVal Data As SomeMessage)
        'either this or raising the event on main gui
        Dim type As String = Data.Type.ToString()

        Select Case type
            Case is = "Done"
                ' Finished work
                ' Writes something to the server and calls Done() method
                ' On the calling class, move to the next element  
        End Select 
        'Or RaiseEvent Packet(Data)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Done()
        SW.Dispose()
        SW = Nothing

        ' Here we indicate that we have finished processing the current item.
        processingFinished = True
    End Sub

End Class
```